# VS Code: Reopen windows after restart

Tags: visual-studio-code, multiple-instances

I usally have multiple instances of VS Code running, working on different projects simultaneously. After a system restart I always have to reopen those windows manually ([File > Open Recent] may be a quick way, but still...).

Is there a way to do this more easily, for example using some kind of window management extension?

Comment: write a shell script that launches multiple code instances and give the required folder or workspace as argument

Answer (score 1):

I found on Github a issue with the same approach: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26773

There they talk about `"window.reopenFolders": "all"`

Comment: Thanks, sadly this setting doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Comment: That setting is now called `window.restoreWindows` but unfortunately it does nothing for me. Launching VS Code for the first time still opens only one window, even if I was working on several projects, each in its own window.

Comment: For me it was opening only one windows because I was right clicking in VSCode icon and closing all windows. But it works if I click on File -> Exit. This way when we reopen VSCode, all windows will be reopened.

Comment: are you on Windows? this is I guess should be an operating system feature for any app not only VSCode, like in Macos